# Button from an iframe in WebBrowser does not work

Tags: codenameone

I am using the WebBrowser component. There is a button in an iframe which when clicked has to trigger redirect. The redirection is not happening and I am given the android code below to use it to make redirection work.

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);// setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);

Do I have to
1. Create a cn1 plugin so I use the android code
2. Or those settings come by default with the WebBrowser component for android.
3. Or is there another stuff I have to do to get the button to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can access any of the set* methods on the settings using `BrowserComponent.setProperty()` e.g.:

```
myBc.setProperty("AllowContentAccess", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Notice that this might fail if a special permission is required.

Comment: It seems the iframe is the major culprit. The button in the iframe is not seen by the BrowserComponent.executeAndReturnString method but the iframe itself is seen.
This has nothing to do with the BrowserComponent. I run tests on another arrogant(too big to fail) API provider which doesn't use iframe after payment and it works fine there.
The initial API provider has agreed to change the iframe so I will have to wait for that.
Thanks for the assistance.